# Trouble with DataGridView.DefaultView.RowFilter when searching through all columns using C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, rowfilter

I am currently trying to use the RowFilter method to locate records that match a criteria. The code I am using to perofrm this is :-

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.AppendFormat("Stock Number Like '%{0}%' OR Title Like '%{0}%' OR Listing Title Like '%{0}%' OR Description Like '%{0}%'", txtProductSearch.Text);  
dataTableProduct.DefaultView.RowFilter = sb.ToString();
```

However, when it is ran I get the following error :-

```
Syntax error: Missing operand after 'Number' operator.
```

I have tried different formats for the String but all have been unsuccessful. How could this be altered to allow the search to proceed as it should?

Comment: Number is an operator by the looks of it.  Put the name in backticks so it knows it is `Stock Number` and not `Stock` number

Comment: Now it doesn't result in an error but doesn't find any data that it should.

Comment: Try simplifying the query just to be sure it is working.  Just do one portion, then the next, that way you can find out what is failing in the query. Oh and depending on the original query which gives you the data set, you may need to filter based on the original names of the fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing Stock Number to [Stock Number].

Comment: ..and  Listing Title to [Listing Title]

Comment: Thanks, don't know how I overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

Spaces in the field names is most likely the problem. For SQL Server, field names need to be wrapped in brackets [Field Name] if they are keywords, or contain spaces. In my opinion, it is best to avoid spaces in column names when possible. Use an underscore 'Field_Name' or no space 'FieldName'.